# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined (Angular 8)

Tags: html, angular

Am always getting this error 'Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined' in my html code. But my the data from the api is perfectly loading, what do i do to resolve this error.(Angular 8)

I think this is occurring  because my data is not getting loaded instantly and it is taking time, but eventually it is getting loaded. The error is showing in this line '*ngIf="!systemCheck && systemCheck && !canEdit"

```
<span *ngIf="!systemCheck && systemCheck && !canEdit">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Save
              </button>
            </span>


this.stakeholderService.getVendorStatus(this.statusID).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
        if(!result){
          this.flag = false;
        }
        else {
          this.flag = true;

        let userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
        if (userRole == AppConstants.SUPERADMIN_ROLE_NAME) {
          this.canEdit = true;
        }
        else {
          this.canEdit = false;
        }
        this.modelVendorStatus = result;

        this.color = result.colourCode;

        if (this.color != null && this.color != "" && this.color != undefined) {
          this.showBox = true;
        }

        this.systemCheck = result.isSystem;

        if(this.modelVendorStatus) {

        this.vendorStatusForm.patchValue({
          entityType: result.entityType,
          description: result.description,
          isDefault: result.isDefault,
          isSystem: result.isSystem,
          colourCode: result.colourCode,
          sortOrder: result.sortOrder,
          title: result.title,
        });
      }
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = error;
        if (error.status === 401)
          this.router.navigate(["/logout"]);
      });
```

The error goes like this

```
VendorStatusEditComponent.html:115 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (VM66404 VendorStatusEditComponent.ngfactory.js:555)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:39364)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38376)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:38670)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38383)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:39716)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:39299)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:27092)
    at ApplicationRef.tick (core.js:35380)
```

part where that I missed, sorry for that

```
<div *ngIf="modelVendorStatus.ID > 0">
      <div>
        <hr/>
      </div>
      <app-record-info [record]=modelVendorStatus></app-record-info>
    </div>
```

Comment: Initialize your id variable if you are using it as a class variable.May be like `id="";`

Comment: Am not using any variable called id in my .ts file. I want to know how to use async pipes at this line so that it will wait to fetch the data.

Comment: You are not using id there, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: please post your ts file also

Comment: i will post the code , sorry for that

Comment: probably async can help !(systemCheck | async) && (systemCheck | async)) && !canEdit

Comment: I believe it's probably because of wrong referencing, check my answer.

Comment: Remember that undefined means it hasn't been declared yet, null means it just doesn't have a value for it. Consider instantiating your variable, and remember that you can give it the value null.

Comment: where are you using `ID` in your html where error is thrown? Not seeing anywhere?

Comment: @Poldo i have checked the same still i cant get it right

Comment: @Parthan_akon  if you are using vs code then do a full project search  or search in `VendorStatusEditComponent.html` for `.ID`  go through all the searches  and to fix the same use safe navigation operator for example `myvariable?.ID`. The code you have posted here has nothing to do with the error shown. The error indicates that  you are trying to access a property of a null object somewhere like `{{ sampleVariable.ID }}`  when the value is null for the variable `sampleVariable` the above error is shown

Comment: @JoelJoseph . You were right , I found the variable , I'll update the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add a **?** after **modelVendorStatus** in html

instead of

```
<div *ngIf="modelVendorStatus.ID > 0">
```

try this

```
<div *ngIf="modelVendorStatus?.ID > 0">
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is coming from observable you'll be needing async pipe in your html.

```
*ngIf="!(systemCheck | async) && !canEdit"
```

Comment: It won't work as systemCheck is a boolean, not an observable.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Observable, you need to properly reference the properties, I am assuming that you are using it inside onInit like this, then you must use another variable to reference, eg:

```
ngOnInit(){

const that = this;  //inside subscribe use that instead of this

this.stakeholderService.getVendorStatus(this.statusID).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
        ........
        ........
        that.systemCheck = result.isSystem; //here I've replaced this with that
        ........
        ........
       }
}
```

> This is because inside the Observable, the **`this`** reference won't
>   work so you need to create a reference to this.

Comment: you don't need to do such thing, this is correctly referenced inside the the observable as the common way to get result is `observable().subscribe(result => this.result = result)`

Comment: Yash Krishan, nope `this` is not the issue here